# delinkify links in OT close reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I just went to cast a close vote on a programming question and instead of clicking the radio button on the option about programming questions being off topic here my mouse bumped and I hit the link instead.

[image]

This wouldn't be a problem, but the link opens in the same window so it took me away from the page I was working on.

[image]

Could links in close reasons either be removed, or at least set to target=new so that focus is not taken away from the task at hand by an accidental click?

Comment: I know this is a duplicate because I've seen this before, but now I can't find it :P +1

Comment: @Doorknob I tried to close it as a dup but I kept misclicking on links in the close reasons so I gave up.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah yes, that's the question I was looking for. I even upvoted it already :P